# Sass directives mixin, include, =, and +

Tags: css, stylesheet, sass

I've been picking up Sass as I go on the project I'm working on and have noticed `@mixin` and `@include` being replaced with `=` and `+` respectively. I can't seem to find any information on these symbols as directives and sass-lang.com only makes mention to the @ prefixed directives.

Seeing these have brought up a few questions that I cannot seem to find answered here, on google, or at http://www.sass-lang.com.

1. Is it good practice to use `=` and `+` over their longer equivalents?
2. Are there any differences between using them and the @ directives?
3. Are there any more directives that are replaced with symbols like `@extend`?
4. Will these work with sass and scss / even if they do, which style is more common in which flavor of sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old syntax for the .sass files (Pre SASS3)

see here under "Mixins": http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SCSS_FOR_SASS_USERS.html

Moving forward, you should use @mixin and @include, unless you have a reason for continuing to use the legacy format.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's why I didn't see any mention of the `+` or `=`.

Comment: It's a shame as I'm lazy and liked the 1 char syntax :-)

Comment: Isn't the smaller syntax why we all use haml anyway? I do agree that it's easier to read with `@mixin` and `@include`.